# Syntax exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting a syntax exception in this code at a** + b** **==** c**: i don't know what the prob is help me out..

```
def getValue():
    a, b,c =1,2,3;

    while a:
        while b:
            while c:
                if a + b + c ==  1000 and a** + b** == c**:
                        print("A : {} B : {} C:{}".format( a, b, c))
                        return a*b*c;
                else:
                    c += 1;
            b += 1;
        a+=1;


print("Answer : {}".format(getValue()))
```

For guys who put negative to my question i accept the mistake i did but giving the negatives to my post make me feel not to ask this question. If it is not related to any topic on this site, you can provide negative. But for mistakes i do and ask for help to review and even if you find it silly as i did after getting to know the mistake you should not give negative, thats demotivating.

Comment: What would you expect `a** + b** == c**` to do?

Comment: `x**y` means x to the power of y, you haven't given the exponent `y`

Comment: I'm guessing that you forgot to add the power to each exponentiation, and the value should be 2 in each case.

Comment: I'm guessing it's supposed to be `a**2 + b**2 = c**2`. (For the record, this is a pretty silly way of trying to find Pythagorean triplets.)

Comment: When do you expect the `while c:` loop to exit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wild guess:

```
if a + b + c ==  1000 and a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
```

Notice that looping over c is really pointless here, you can just use `c = 1000 - b - a`

Also use `for` loops instead of `while`. Are you porting this from some other language?

```
def getValue():
    for a in range(1, 1000):
        for b in range(a, 1000):
            c = 1000 - a - b
            if a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2:
                print("A : {} B : {} C:{}".format(a, b, c))
                return a * b * c
```

Comment: thanks gnibbler. For guys who put negative to my question i accept the mistake i did but giving the negatives to my post make me feel not to ask this question. If it is not related to any topic on this site, you can provide negative. But for mistakes i do and ask for help to review and even if you find it silly as i did after getting to know the mistake you should not give negative, thats demotivating.

Comment: @Vickyonit, One can only guess why you get downvoted if noone leaves a comment. I'll suggest that you could have improved your question with an explanation of what you were trying to do, and taken more care indenting your code. It's not too late, you can still edit it

Comment: thanks for your kind words. I am new to this community i hardly ask ques. This will be my learning. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

`**` operator expects two numerical operands, and you used only one.

Example:

```
>>> 2**3    #2 to the power 3
8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getValue():
    a, b,c =1,2,3;

    while a:
        while b:
            while c:
                if a + b + c ==  1000 and a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
                        print("A : {} B : {} C:{}".format( a, b, c))
                        return a*b*c;
                else:
                    c += 1;
            b += 1;
        a+=1;


print("Answer : {}".format(getValue()))
```